# SQL Server automatically generate all the years in between and repeating values for each year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to generate all the years between two numbers, like 2000 and 2010 and for each year, I need a set of repeating values in the second column. 
Eg;

```
Year       Value
2000       Spring Term
2000       Fall Term
2001       Spring Term
2001       Fall Term
```

And it should go on until 2010. I am able to generate the years between two number using the below script:

```
; with  CTE as
    (
    select  year('2006') as yr
    union all
    select  yr + 1
    from    CTE
    where   yr < year('2013')
    )   
    select  yr  from    CTE
```

However, I am not able to generate the repeating values for each year. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and "dirty" way would be with a `LEFT-JOIN`:

```
;with CTE
as (
    select year('2006') as yr   
    union all
    select yr + 1
    from CTE
    where yr < year('2013')
    )
select yr
    , r.term
from CTE
left join (
    select 'Spring Term' [term]
    union all
    select 'Fall Term'
    ) r on 1 = 1;
```

or with a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
;with CTE
as (
    select year('2006') as yr   
    union all
    select yr + 1
    from CTE
    where yr < year('2013')
    )
select yr
    , r.term
from CTE
cross join (
    select term
    from (
        values ('Sprint Term'), ('Fall Term')
        ) as tbl(term)
    ) r;
```